# Element not being taken out of document flow

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I've got a css issue that I just don't really understand. Usually when you float divs they get taken out of the document flow. So for example if you have two divs and you float one of them left then the one below it would "come up" as if the first one never existed.

If for example I have

```
<div>
    <div class="" style="float:right; width:95%; background:red; height:400px;">

    </div>
    <div class="" style="width:200px; height:200px; background:yellow">
      hi
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Then the yellow box has come up to the top as if the red box never existed. **So far so good.**

What I don't understand is that if i put a video element inside the yellow box then it will not sit outside document flow even if I force it to be rendered as a block element.

For example

```
<div>
    <div class="" style="float:right; width:95%; background:red; height:400px;">

    </div>
    <div class="" style="width:200px; height:200px; background:yellow">
      <video autoplay muted playsinline style="width:70%; display:block;">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/236872382.hd.mp4?s=ac279f17c02a3262e748ebc2920b85f68740c7c1&profile_id=174" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

For example here the video is rendering beneath the red block. **Why is the video (blue logo animation) not ignoring the red block which is floated?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the width. The width is too small for the video element. You can update the width.

```html
<div>
  <div class="" style="float:right; width:80%; background:red; height:400px;">

  </div>
  <div class="" style="width:20%; height:400px; background:yellow">
    <video autoplay muted playsinline style="width:100%; display:block;">
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/236872382.hd.mp4?s=ac279f17c02a3262e748ebc2920b85f68740c7c1&profile_id=174" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I have misunderstood how floats work. I understand that if you just make the red div 80% and right floated and the movie 20% then there is no issue but i thought that the red block was basically ignored because it sits outside of the document flow but i can see now that isn't the case. If you add a little bit of text inside the yellow box then it will fit nicely but if you add a lot then the whole block of text will get pushed below the red box. I thought it would just be displayed behind the red box. My bad i guess.